# $0.9$ chance to get blue, $0.1$ chance to get red, but $0.05$ chance that the color will be switched

Tags: probability

Let's say that every morning there is a $90\%$ chance that Tom puts a blue ball and a $10\%$ chance he puts a red ball in Susan's mailbox. However, there is a $25\%$ chance that Sally will come along after Tom and switch the color of the ball. What are the probabilities that the ball in Susan's mailbox is blue or red on any given morning?

Probability of blue ball = $0.9 * 0.75 = 0.675$

Probability of red ball = $0.1 * 0.75 = 0.075$

But this cannot be correct since $0.675 + 0.075$ do not add up to $1$?

Comment: There are 4 cases. (blue/red) X (switch/no-switch). In your calculation only 2 are presented

Comment: They add up to $.75$, the probability that Sally doesn't switch the ball.

Answer (score 1):

Prob of getting blue is sum of the prob of tom putting blue ball and sally not switching and the prob of tom putting the red ball and sally switching, so a total of
$$ 0.9\cdot 0.75 + 0.1\cdot 0.25 = 0.7 $$
Similarly the prob of getting red is
$$ 0.1\cdot 0.75 + 0.9\cdot0.25 = 0.3 $$

These clearly add up to $1$.